# How to use default parameters to initiate an array of objects property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the constructor to provide default parameters for a class property, which is an object . . . inside of which is an array of objects. Nothing I try works . . .

What I want to end up with is having the `rowData` property of the `authData` object be an array with one just entry (an object). . . i.e. `authData`:

```
 {"catText": {"catName": "User Data", . . . },
 "rowData": [{
                 {"userName":'', "style":{ . . .}, 
                    . . . 
                 {"uID": "User ID", "style"{: . . . "width": 3}
            }]
 }
```

One approach I tried is below, with `Object.values().map(obj => [obj])` but this isn't working. The (simplified) code (which doesn't compile . .. `'A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation . . . A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation' . . .`) is below:

```
export interface AuthBlock {
    "catText": {"catName": string}
    "rowData": {
        "userName": {"Username": string,"style": {"type": string, "width": number}}, 
        "password":{"Password": string,"style": {"type": string, "width": number}}, 
        "uId":{"User ID": string,"style": {"type": string, "width": number}}
    }[]
}

export class AuthRow {

    constructor(
        public authData: AuthBlock = {
            "catText": {"catName": "User Data"},
            "rowData": Object.values({{
                "userName": {"Username": '',"style": {"type": "text", "width": 3}}, 
                "password":{"Password": '',"style": {"type": "password", "width": 5}}, 
                "uId":{"User ID": '',"style": {"type": "text", "width": 3}}
            }}).map(obj => [obj])
        }
    ){}
}
```

Many thanks in advance if any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.keys(obj.rowData)
      .map(key => ({ [key]: obj.rowData[key] }))
```

Get the keys on the object, use map to convert it to an array, and transform it into separate objects.

EDIT:

```
export interface AuthBlock {
    "catText": {"catName": string}
    "rowData": {
        "userName": {"Username": string,"style": {"type": string, "width": number}}, 
        "password":{"Password": string,"style": {"type": string, "width": number}}, 
        "uId":{"User ID": string,"style": {"type": string, "width": number}}
    }[]
}

export class AuthRow {

    constructor(
        public authData: AuthBlock = {
            "catText": {"catName": "User Data"},
            // Open array here
            "rowData": [{
                "userName": {"Username": '',"style": {"type": "text", "width": 3}}, 
                "password":{"Password": '',"style": {"type": "password", "width": 5}}, 
                "uId":{"User ID": '',"style": {"type": "text", "width": 3}}
            }]
            // Close here
        }
    ){}
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, and that's a good solution under normal circumstances (i.e., inside a function), but I'm trying to do this inside a constructor, and unless I mis-formatted something, the constructor is not allowing this. Part of the problem, I believe, lies in passing an array by value as a parameter, and I'm worried that the constructor doesn't even want to allow conversion of object to array in the parameter list . . . But hopefully I'm wrong on that and there is a solution somehow.

Comment: . . . also, parameters aside, won't Object.keys(obj.rowData) return several keys, thus giving an array of length 3? (i.e. the keys inside the "rowData" object: "userName", "password", "uId"). I'm just looking to obtain an array of length one that contains everything.

Comment: For instance, if foo = {"a": {"a1":0}, "b":{"b1": 1, "b2": 2}}, then Object.keys(foo.b) = ["b1", "b2"] (which is an array of length two, whereas I'm aiming for an array of length one).

Comment: Can you update your question to contain exactly your intended data outcome? I don't understand the objective.

Comment: Oh! Nevermind, I understand what you would like. Updating answer

Comment: Many thanks. Just checking, was your edit the updated answer you referred to, or are you still updating? If convenient, if you'd put the solution in the edit are you just made, that would be extremely helpful. The solution I tried did have `Object.keys` in the location you indicated, but I think it still wanted to enumerate all the sub-properties in `"rowData"`. There's also the problem of how in the map function to refer to the object in the "rowData" property, as literal notation (i.e. {"a": 1, "b":2}.b or {"a": 1, "b":2}['b']) doesn't work.